# How to get query with values from com.datastax.driver.core.PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I am using datastax cassandra driver. How to get query with values from com.datastax.driver.core.PreparedStatement ?

The toString() method does not give any meaningful thing. I want to print the exact query string in logs.

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the query string from a `PreparedStatement` with the `getQueryString` method but you can't get the bound variables because they will be on a `BoundStatement` not a `PreparedStatement`.

I'm not sure if this is the easiest way to get the variables but you could do:

```
for (int index = 0; index < preparedStatement.getVariables().size(); index++) {
    log(boundStatement.getObject(index).toString());
}
```

You would have to construct a single query string yourself because the driver keeps the query and the bound variables separate.